# My navigation list is overlapping padding. How can I prevent this?

Tags: css, html-lists, padding, overlap

I am trying to make a navigation that highlights the area around the link when you hover over it, and allows you to click on the any area of the highlight to follow that link. It seems that my padding is overlapping and you can only click on the padding to the left of the link, whereas the padding on the right becomes the left padding of the link the the right.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hh7XG/1/

HTML

```
<div id="menubar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href=# >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href=# >About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href=# >Online Courses</a></li>
        <li><a href=# >Registration</a></li>
        <li><a href=# >Faculty</a></li>
        <li><a href=# >Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href=# >Store</a></li>
        <li><a href=# >Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href=# >Online Lectures</a></li>
        <li><a href=# >Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href=# >Forum</a></li>
        <li><input class="searchbox" trype="text" value="Search" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Search';"/> </li>
      </ul>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#menubar{
height:auto;
background:#ebebec;
margin-top:0px;
padding-top:0px;
padding-left:0px;
}
ul{
list-style-type:none;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
#menubar ul li{
text-decoration:none;
color:#005da4;
text-align:center;
margin:none;
width:auto;
padding-left:0;
padding-right:0;
float:left;
}
#menubar ul li:hover a{
background:#acce39;
}
#menubar ul li a{
text-decoration:none;
color:#005da4;
display:block;
width:100%;
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:20px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
text-align:center;
margin-left:0;
margin-right:0;
}
.searchbox
{
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px;
    margin-left:15px;
    align:left;
}
```

(Sorry if the below does not make sense. I would be more than happy to clarify.)

I want it to display like this: (| is the border between li's)

```
|    Link    |    Link    |    Link    |
```

When I hover over the padding to the right of the leftmost link, I would like it to look like this: (X is the highlight, ^ is my mouse)

```
|XXXXLinkXXXX|    Link    |    Link
           ^
```

but it is acting like this:

```
|    Link|    Link|    Link    |
```

When the mouse is hovering over the leftmost link the highlight looks like this:

```
|XXXXLinkXXXX|Link    |    Link
    ^
```

but when I hover over the padding to the right of of the link it looks like this:

```
|    Link|XXXXLinkXXXX|Link    |
           ^
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using `padding` property on your anchor tags to increase their width, it doesn't need to specify `width: 100%`. Just remove that, and it works:

```css
#menubar ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#005da4;
    display:block;    /* Since li element is floated itself */
                      /* it doesn't need to use inline-block value for display */

    /* width:100%; */ /* <-- remove this declaration */
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
}
```

**[Edited Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/Hh7XG/4/)**.

Comment: Thank you! When I removed the 'width:100%;' it worked. However, when I removed the 'display:block;' attribute, it shifted up and the highlight extended above the div.

Comment: @ExperimentsWithCode You're welcome, but please note that I didn't say to remove `display:block;` :) I meant using `inline-block` is useless in this case, It's better to use `block` instead, as I did ;)

Comment: Ahhh, my fault. I was wondering where you got block from, I even double checked that I wrote it as inline block. Thanks again! That seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Hh7XG/3/
I added `padding` to the li also.

Comment: This is very interesting. The hover highlight area no longer overlaps, however, when I highlight the right padding, I can only move my mouse half the padding distance before it turns off. I went with the above posters answer, but I appreciate you taking the time to try to help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This gave me the effect you're looking for....

```
#menubar ul li{
text-decoration:none;
color:#005da4;
text-align:center;
margin:none;
width:auto;
padding-left:0;
padding-right:20px; // changed
float:left;
}
#menubar ul li:hover a{
background:#acce39;
}
#menubar ul li a{
text-decoration:none;
color:#005da4;
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
padding-left:10px; // changed
padding-right:10px; // changed
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
text-align:center;
margin-left:0;
margin-right:0;
}
```

Comment: This made all the 'li's display one on top of the other rather than side by side. I am not specifically why that change occurred.

Comment: Because you left out the rest of the CSS? I only copied this area because it contained the three styles that I'd changed. You still need the rest of the file. LOL